# ElasticSearch Index Modeling

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch (you will figure out after reading the question!) and I need help in designing ElastiSearch index for a dataset similar to described in the example below.

I have data for companies in Russell 2000 Index. To define an index for these companies, I have the following mapping -

`

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "company": { 
      "_all":       { "enabled": false  }, 
      "properties": { 
        "ticker": { "type": "text"  }, 
        "name": { "type": "text"  },
        "CEO": { "type": "text"  },
        "CEO_start_date": {"type": "date"},
        "CEO_end_date": {"type": "date"}   
      }
    }
}
```

`

As CEO of a company changes, I want to update end_date of the existing document and add a new document with start date.

Here, 
(1) For such dataset what is an ideal id scheme? Since I want to keep multiple documents should I consider (company_id + date) combination as id
(2) Since CEO changes are infrequent should Time Based indexing considered in this case?

Comment: It seems like your question is more about what data model to choose rather than something specific to Elasticsearch itself. I have a couple of recommendations. (a) ES is perhaps not the best choice for primary datastore (in case you were considering this), more: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/resiliency/current/index.html (b) I'd recommend not building logic into an identifier as I've found this unnecessarily constraining in the past. (c) If you're using an alternate primary datastore, keep identifiers consistent across ES and the primary datastore.

Answer (score 0):

You're schema is a reasonable starting point, but I would make a few minor changes and comments:

**Recommendation 1:**

First, in your proposed schema you probably want to change ticker to be of type **keyword** instead of text.  **Keyword** allows you to use **terms** queries to do an exact match on the field.

The **text** type should be used when you want to match against analyzed text.  Analyzing text applies normalizations to your text data to make it easier to match something a user types into a search bar.  For example common words like "the" will be dropped and word endings like "ing" will be removed.  Depending on how you want to search for names in your index you may also want to switch that to **keyword**.  Also note that you have the option of indexing a field twice using BOTH **keyword** and **text** if you need to support both search methods.

**Recommendation 2:**

Sid raised a good point in his comment about using this a primary store.  I have used ES as a primary store in a number of use cases with a lot of success.  I think the trade off you generally make by selecting ES over something more traditional like an RDBMS is you get way more powerful read operations (searching by any field, full text search, etc) but lose relational operations (joins).  Also I find that loading/updating data into ES is slower than an RDBMS due to all the extra processing that has to happen.  So if you are going to use the system primarily for updating and tracking state of operations, or if you rely heavily on JOIN operations you may want to look at using a RDBMS instead of ES.

As for your questions:

**Question 1: ID field**

You should check whether you really need to create an explicit ID field.  If you do not create one, ES will create one for that is guaranteed to be unique and evenly distributed.  Sometimes you will still need to put your own IDs in though.  If that is the case for your use case then adding a new field where you combine the company ID and date would probably work fine.

**Question 2: Time based index**

Time based indices are useful when you are going to have lots of events.  They make it easy to do maintenance operations like deleting all records older than X days.  If you are just indexing CEO changes to 2000 companies you probably won't have very many events.  I would probably skip them since it adds a little bit of complexity that doesn't buy you much in this use case.